# localhost wont connect to mailserver

Tags: c#, email, smtp, localhost, mail-server

```
public bool send()
{
    try
    {
        string body = _omschrijving;
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress("info@mydomain.com", "userfrom");
        var toAddress = new MailAddress("randomemail@gmail.com", "userto");

        const string subject = "mailmessage";

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = an IP address provided by the webhosting company,
              UseDefaultCredentials = false,
              DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
              Credentials = new NetworkCredential("info@mydomain.com", "password")
        };

        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            Body = "naam: " + _naam + "<br />mail: " + _email + "<br />content: " + body
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the code I use to send mails with a simple form on my website. _omschrijving, _email, _naam are fields from the class the method is in. I also changed information like passwords for security purposes.
I tried using this from my localhost and it failed. It could not connect to the server.

I tried publishing my project to the webserver (where the mailserver is also located) and it worked perfectly.

I'm glad it works, but I wonder why it wouldn't connect to the mailserver when debugging on the localhost?
Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes your hoster configured his mail-server to only accept connections from his very own webservers which is also common practice for database-severs

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the hosting company limits connections to its SMTP server only to hosted machines? If so, your local machine's request will be denied.

Answer (score 0):

I tried connecting to my new mailserver with outlook and I discovered what the problem was. My ISP does not allow their users to use a third party mail server to send outgoing mail. The solution is to use my ISP's outgoing SMTP server. Not that it matters for the form in production, because it's hosted somewhere else.